# Mongoose not closing connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

it seems that i have a problem with mongoose configuration / development.
I instantiate the connections as follows:

```
var con = mongoose.createConnection(baseUri, { server: { poolSize: 1 }, socketOptions: { keepAlive: 0, connectTimeoutMS: 10000 }});
```

For my understanding they should be closed after 10 seconds. Am i wrong on my assumption ? Is it correct to work with this coding (keepAlive: 0, connectionTimeoutMS: 10000 ??

In the mongo log i can see that the connections are not closed:

```
2015-10-22T19:38:55.250+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56345 #20 (20 connections now open)
2015-10-22T19:38:55.258+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56346 #21 (21 connections now open)
2015-10-22T19:38:55.258+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56347 #22 (22 connections now open)
```

I expect up to 2000 concurrent users in my application and i just want to prevent mongodb from crashing!

BR,
Martin

Comment: When you close the application do the connections close?

Comment: Yes they do close if i close the application

Answer (score 1):

Martin,

The `connectionTimeoutMS` argument will determine the maximum amount of time your driver (Mongoose) will wait for a connection to be established with the server. This is only used when the client is first making a connection to the database. If your connections close when you close the application, the behavior is working as supposed to.

If you are worried about timeout issues, for development I would start with a relatively low timeout value and slowly increase it if you face regular timeouts. Generally you can start with a timeout of 5 seconds. For Production or connections made through a PaaS such as Heroku, you might consider a higher timeout since your application is likely running in a container that can be "idled" or "passivated" during periods of low activity. For example, on this issue MongoLab recommends setting timeout to 30 seconds. See here: [MongoLab Recommended Mongoose Settings.](https://gist.github.com/mongolab-org/9959376).

You should enable keepAlive if you will have long running applications.

If your issue is with the overhead, you mentioned MongoDB crashing with 2000 concurrent users, every connection to MongoDB has an overhead which contributes to the required memory for the system. If you suspect a high number of users and for production quality operation you want to look into [MongoDB Replication](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/) it may pay off to start using a monitoring tool like [MongoStat](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) to monitor a running mongod